# Format array strings to a comma delimited file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have an array that looks like the following.

```
X = ['2.2    31452- MMMMM   25 EA       1.2 AC - Auto   Uni','20Eye      Customer: 300xxxx       ','Order Number: 215987 Salesperson: Barbara']
```

As you can see, there is no readable format, since it is not space delimited or tab delimited. Some spaces are single and others vary from 2,3,4 etc. How can I format the data so it's in this format:

```
X = ['2.2,31452- MMMMM,25 EA,1.2 AC - Auto,Uni,20Eye,Customer: 300xxxx,Order Number: 215987,Salesperson: Barbara']
```

Essentially I want to write the results to a csv file.

Comment: Do you have any rules about how to split your input? For instance, "25 EA", why this turns out to be 25 EA without a comma?

Comment: @Albert Lee Hi, no this would not be a big issue at all.

Comment: I think I figured out the rules, one space is not a delimiter, but more than one continuous space should be a delimiter, I'll write an algorithm for you.

Comment: what are the headers to your csv file? @Cesar

Comment: @AlbertLee the last element of list has one space and then also it is separated by comma

Comment: @YamanJain, gocha, so,  there seems to be no rules at all, hmmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
X = ['2.2    31452- MMMMM   25 EA       1.2 AC - Auto   Uni', '20Eye      Customer: 300xxxx       ',
     'Order Number: 215987 Salesperson: Barbara']

delimiter = ','


def extract(s):
    SPACE = ' '
    result = []
    start = 0
    end = 0
    already_encounter_space = False
    continous_space = False
    for idx, c in enumerate(s):
        if c != SPACE:
            if already_encounter_space:
                if continous_space:
                    result.append(s[start:end + 1])
                    start = idx
                else:
                    end = idx
            else:
                end = idx
            already_encounter_space = False
            continous_space = False
        else:
            if already_encounter_space:
                continous_space = True
            else:
                already_encounter_space = True
    result.append(s[start:end + 1])
    return result


tmp = list()
for s in X:
    tmp.extend(extract(s))

X = [delimiter.join(tmp)]

print X
```

We got anwser like this:

```
['2.2,31452- MMMMM,25 EA,1.2 AC - Auto,Uni,20Eye,Customer: 300xxxx,Order Number: 215987 Salesperson: Barbara']
```

Please notice that the last one are not seperated with comma, due to there's only one space in between(Thx to @YamanJain, who remind me of this gotcha). Is this what you want?

Comment: the request result format by the op was how you had it before no? `[...Order Number: 215987, Salesperson: Barbara]` with a comma

Comment: @Albert Lee. This works perfectly! I will modify it if I need I need to change something. But I got the overall concept of your approach. Thanks again!  :D

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal, I found this too but seems that there are no rules at all about the constraint of input. So I can only have a constraint of my own as a precondition.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `regular expression`.

```
re.sub('  +', ',', '  '.join(X))
```

the output comes same as @albert but you can't tweak it.

Comment: Hey, buddy, I like ur approach, very smart move.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a delimiter, you cannot achieve your goal without it. Once you got it, you can simply use the `split` method.